# Git doesn't see my branch from master, how to get it back?

Tags: git

It looks like `master` can't see that one of my branches, `UART_Trans`, exists.

Running `git log` on `master` shows

```
commit ba8a0d8765e9dbb1e73ad08da7617f20b76a79bb (HEAD -> master)
Date:   Mon Nov 19 18:55:27 2018 -0800

    UART_Test working on Basys3 board, using JA pins to send/receive to same board.

commit 35c835ff15ba30c7ea1540ec7e7dad6bae3f5155
Date:   Mon Nov 19 19:45:49 2018 -0800

    UART_Rec simulation works, not tested on board

commit f6deb2bf064382a82c817dc58a9a7b36b464421b
Date:   Sun Nov 18 16:43:33 2018 -0800

    Init
```

But running `git branch` shows

```
  UART_Rec
  UART_Trans  # <-- This clearly exists! But it wasn't in the master git log?
* master
```

And inside of UART_Trans (if I `checkout UART_Trans`), there is:

```
commit ab59f438227473de8a83f4ce402463eec4065f86 (HEAD -> UART_Trans)
Date:   Tue Nov 20 02:31:33 2018 -0800

    UART_Trans working in sim. Not tested on board.

commit f6deb2bf064382a82c817dc58a9a7b36b464421b
Date:   Sun Nov 18 16:43:33 2018 -0800

    Init
```

I'm trying to get the `UART_Trans` branch to be shown as a branch off of `init`. (Also, `UART_Rec` seems to not be on its own branch, despite that the branch exists.) How do I do this?

Side note: I did use `rebase -i init` and deleted the line for `UART_Trans`, which I think is how I ended up in this mess. I did quite a bit of commands I don't fully understand (eg. `rebase`), and while I could just restore (I backed up the file system before trying all this), I'd like to know how to fix it.

Comment: `git log` shows history, not branches.

Comment: Are you asking how to rewrite history to include a commit?

Comment: Sort of. I had `init` branching to all three `UART` modules, for each phase of their development. But `UART_Test`, which I wrote last, I had committed first. So, `git log` showed `init`, then `test`, then `trans` and `rec`. I did a `git rebase -i init` and moved the lines around, but then it looked like it collapsed the branches into one continuous chain (instead of leaving it as branches). So I made sure the `trans` branch still existed, and `rebased` again, this time deleting the line with `trans`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UART_Trans` has diverged from master and that's why you don't see it if, standing on master, you call `git log`. Run `git log UART_Trans` or `git log master UART_Trans` or just `git log --all --graph` instead and you will see it.

Comment: I don't understand why it diverged, though. Eg. I did `git checkout -b UART_Trans2`, then `git cherry-pick <hash_of_working_UART_Trans>`, which copied it onto the branch `UART_Trans2`. Until I do the `cherry-pick`, `git log` on `master` shows `UART_Trans2` as a branch on `init`. After the cherry-pick, it doesn't show anymore. But they both share `init` as a common point, so I don't see why it diverges.

Comment: You added a commit to the branch, this moved the branch pointer, and made the branches diverge.

Comment: Yes, it's how git works basically. If I may make a suggestion, you should go read an article about git branches, such as https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches

Comment: Also read about "merging", as you will want to merge your diverging branches together at some point.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was reading. Somehow I didn't come across anything on `--all`, though, and I misunderstood `log` to list everything. Especially when I ran `git log --graph`, and it didn't show any branches; however, it had originally shown my other branches. (I guess it only shows those branches that eventually merged back?) Sorry to waste time; I genuinely was not understanding.